# Views with exposed filters WITHOUT `Use Ajax`?

Tags: 7, views

Is there a way to use exposed filters, but not require `Use Ajax` ? I want exposed filters but I want it to submit the form and refresh the page.

Comment: If you switch off AJAX in the view then it does a new page load on submit. Do you want to use AJAX elsewhere in the view but just not on the exposed filters?

Comment: If I turned off Ajax exposed filters don't show up.

Comment: That is not correct behavior for Views. You have some other issue that needs to be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use the **Page Display**. That behavior doesn't work when the view is rendered as a block.